# Workspace Switcher inoperative on nVidia dual displays

Tags: nvidia

When I click the Workspace Switcher button (or a button I've mapped to my mouse to do the same task), the screen shows several artifacts and I cannot switch displays properly.

Here is a picture of the display after I've clicked the Workspace Switcher button:

[image]

I have an nVidia n260 video card with dual displays connected

Comment: noone?  I could use some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a compiz plug-in which was incompatible with this version of unity.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to say which compiz plugin it was? This might be useful for other people having the same problem.

Comment: I can't.  I'm sorry.  It was something like desktop wall or cube or something..  I don't know which one.